# How template explicit instantiation works and when?

Tags: c++, template-instantiation

Here is an exercise from C++ primer 5th edition:

"Exercise 16.26: Assuming `NoDefault` is a class that does not have a default constructor, can we explicitly instantiate `vector<NoDefault>`? If not, why not?"

Here is my guess:

Yes we can instantiate it:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void func(){cout << x_.value_ << endl;}
private:
    T x_;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int x) : value_(x){}
    void print(){}
private:
    int value_{};
template <class T>
friend class Foo;
};

extern template class Foo<Bar>; // instantiation declaration
template class  Foo<Bar>; // instantiation definition


int main()
{

  //  Foo<Bar> f;
}
```

The code works fine but if I uncomment the line in main I get error as expected because `Bar` is not default-constructible.

If I use the same class `Bar` as an element type for `std::vector` it doesn't work:

```
extern template class vector<Bar>; // declaration ok
template class vector<Bar>; // instantiation: doesn't work?!
```

- So why my `Foo<Bar>` instantiation works but not `vector<Bar>`?
- What looks to me is that it is logical in `vector<Bar>` not to work because an explicit instantiation definition instantiates all the members (even the ones not used) of the class template; and in this example among them the default constructor of `Foo<Bar>` that implies a default `ctor` of its element type `Bar`; the latter doesn't provide one; after all `Foo<Bar>()` normally is declared as a deleted member function because `x_` doesn't have a default constructor. SO I don't know why `Foo<Bar>` definition works?! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Standard, the [temp.explicit] section explains what happens in an explicit instantiation. In particular, [p12](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#12) provides that:

> An explicit instantiation definition that names a class template specialization explicitly instantiates the class template specialization and is an explicit instantiation definition of only those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation.

Now, `std::vector<T>` has a constructor that takes an integer `n` and initializes the vector with `n` value-initialized `T`'s. It can be assumed that the definition of this constructor is somewhere inside the `<vector>` header (see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/481267)). So the explicit instantiation definition of `std::vector<Bar>` will instantiate that constructor with `T` = `Bar`.

Because this is an *explicit* instantiation, it is not only the signature of that constructor that is instantiated, but its entire body as well. This must, somewhere, include a call to the default constructor of `Bar` (possibly as part of another function that it calls, which would also be instantiated at this point), so a compilation error occurs as part of the explicit instantiation definition of `std::vector<Bar>`. Note that if you were *implicitly* instantiating `std::vector<Bar>`, it would only instantiate (roughly speaking) the signatures of the member functions. This is why it's legal to actually define and use `std::vector<Bar>` objects, as long as you don't call any function that requires the default constructor of `Bar` to exist.

The reason why an explicit instantiation definition of `Foo<Bar>` *succeeds* is that, when `Foo<Bar>` is instantiated, the compiler marks its default constructor as deleted (this always happens whenever there is a non-default-constructible non-static member). It therefore does not at any point attempt to compile any code that requires the default constructor of `Bar`, and no error occurs.

Comment: Hmm, so the explicit instantiation is not ill-formed necessarily?

Comment: @cigien yes, I believe that hypothetically it may succeed as explained in the footnote, but in practice you will not see this happen

Comment: @cigien Actually, I changed my mind. I think that strategy is no longer allowed in C++20, since most members of `std::vector` are now `constexpr`.

Comment: I'm not sure why the `constexpr`ness of the members would prevent that strategy. It's still allowed to split the declaration and definition if wanted I think.

Comment: @cigien But you can't defer the definition to the end of the TU if it's `constexpr`. I mean, you could, but it would result in that function not being usable in constant expressions at all, since all uses would necessarily precede the definition. I don't think the standard can possibly be interpreted in a way that would make that result conforming.

Comment: Hmm, no, and if could be interpreted that way, it would be considered a wording defect. Nice answer, looks good to me.

Comment: You are really genius! because the default constructor of `Foo` is defined as a deleted function then the compiler doesn't instantiate it consequently it doesn't need the default constructor of `Bar`. To ensure what I'm saying: just add a user-defined default constructor to `Foo` that is explicitly defined (not marked as default so not synthesized by the compiler) then the instantiation definition will fail as with `vector<Bar>`:
template <typename T>
class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo(){}
   // Foo() = default 

  As you can see now the previous code doesn't work with `Foo<Bar`

Comment: If I define `Foo()=default` will be deleted too hence the code wrks fine with `Foo<Bar` but `Foo(){}` wil cause an eror because it will be instantiated thus needs Bar default ctor whis is missing consequently an error. I think this is why vector<Bar> doesn't work because it has a default ctor defined (not deleted ) thus it needs thd default one of its element type.